# Keep Radio Checked After Submit

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

How do i keep the radio checked after user submitted the form? 
User will stay on the same page after submit. Is there any other way except AJAX? I am not familiar with AJAX, prefer PHP.

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
<div id="radioboomboomboom">
<input type="radio" name="branch"  value="[KL]" required> KL <br>
<input type="radio" name="branch"  value="[JB]"  required> JB <br>
<input type="radio" name="branch"  value="[PG]"  required> Penang <br>
<input type="radio" name="branch"  value="[MLK]"  required> Melacca</div> 
<br>
<input type="submit" name= "submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: you goes to next page or stay on same page after form submit?

Comment: stay on the same page.

Comment: If you use AJAX, it will not refresh the page

Comment: i dont want to use AJAX, is there any others way? prefer php @MarkoPaju

Comment: @AlivetoDie yesss, it works =D sorry for late reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check POST data and based on that add `checked` attribute to the corresponding radio button.

***Do like this:-***

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
    <div id="radioboomboomboom">
        <input type="radio" name="branch"  value="[KL]" <?php if(isset($_POST['branch']) && $_POST['branch'] =='[KL]' ){echo "checked";}?> required> KL <br>
        <input type="radio" name="branch"  value="[JB]"  <?php if(isset($_POST['branch']) && $_POST['branch'] =='[JB]' ){echo "checked";}?> required> JB <br>
        <input type="radio" name="branch"  value="[PG]"  <?php if(isset($_POST['branch']) && $_POST['branch'] =='[PG]' ){echo "checked";}?> required> Penang <br>
        <input type="radio" name="branch"  value="[MLK]"  <?php if(isset($_POST['branch']) && $_POST['branch'] =='[MLK]' ){echo "checked";}?> required> Melacca
    </div> 
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name= "submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh yessssss, it works. Thankyou and sorry for late reply!

Comment: @JtTan  glad to help you :):)